# Range based for loop starts at one instead of zero?

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, mingw-w64

I have just started using range based for loops to simplify my code when using templates. I have come across a strange error and am not sure if this is something that I am missing or if the compiler is making a mistake. I have written a piece of code to illustrate the issue that I am having as well as the output. These are shown below.

**Note:** I am using the Mingw64 compiler on windows `g++ (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1` compiled without optimization with the `--std=c++11` flag.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int  main()
{
    // Declares an array of size 5 and of type int and intialises.
    std::array<int,5> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector<int> y = {1,2,3,4,5};

    // Prints each element
    std::cout << "Array:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x" << "\t" << "i" << std::endl;
    for (auto i  : x)
    {
        std::cout << x[i] << "\t" << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Vector" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y" << "\t" << "i" << std::endl;
    for (auto i : y)
    {
        std::cout << y[i] << "\t" << i << std::endl;
    }
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array:
x       i
2       1
3       2
4       3
5       4
0       5
Vector
y       i
2       1
3       2
4       3
5       4
1313429340      5
```

I would assume that the last line of both the vector and array output is an overflow, and notice how `i` starts at one instead of zero?? I would have assumed it would behave as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: `i` is the value of the element in the array/vector not the index. It starts from 1 because that is the value of the 1st element.

Comment: Try to initialize the array with `{3,2,1,4,5}`. How's that?

Comment: Wow, all those calls to `std::endl`! That stream will certainly be thoroughly flushed! (just use `'\n`; it's all that's needed here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have not understood the syntax correctly

```
for (auto i  : x)
```

here `i` is not an index of an array, it is the actual element inside the vector `x`.
So it is doing its job correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, am feeling a bit stupid now :)

Answer (score 0):

"i" is the actual value in the array and not the index. So it is printing x[1] to x[5] in the first column and 1 to 5 in the second column. To access the values just print "i".

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto i : x)
```

creates copies of elements in x to be used inside your for loop. Use an iterator instead to access elements by their index.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << x[i] << "\t" << i << std::endl;
}
```